# Found same SubscriberId in text response template after reply

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcedx-cli, mobileconnect

We are sending SMS from sales cloud using API integration and trying to store replies in the sales cloud from the marketing cloud. so for that purpose, we have created Text response template with AMPScript and next keyword to capture replies. Here if we send SMS to two different contact with same mobile number we are not able to capture correct reply subscriberId.In text response template after reply, we are capturing subscriberid but found its coming same for all the replies.

eg: we sent first SMS to the contact "A" with mobile number '123' and again we sent the second SMS to contact "B" with same mobile number '123'(sales cloud contact recordId is contact key in marketing cloud) and After reply , using text response template we found its capturing first contact subscriberId for all the replies.so how to capture correct subscriberId or subscriberKey after reply?.

eg code:

```
%%[ Var @SubId,@mobileNumber

@mobileNumber=MOBILE_NUMBER
@SubId=subscriberId

]%%
```

related post:https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/5449/eliot-harper

Comment: Can one phone number be assigned to multiple customers in your Sales Cloud org?

Comment: hi Rafal, Yes, or we are thinking of some scenarios like, in case the contact got deleted(sales cloud) or the same mobile number is updated on the new contact then based on the new contact, the SMS reply has to redirect.